# The difference between task context and process context in Linux kernel

Tags: process, linux-kernel, tasks

I was reading Linux kernel Document and found in some places, they use task context and process context.

```
linux/Documentation$ grep -R "task context" .
./driver-model/driver.txt:147:The probe() entry is called in task context, with the     bus's rwsem locked
./DocBook/device-drivers.tmpl:429:  this writing all such functions are usable only from task context.
./gpio.txt:141:a task context.  However, for spinlock-safe GPIOs it's OK to use them
./gpio.txt:258:a task context.  However, for spinlock-safe GPIOs it's OK to request GPIOs
./PCI/pci-error-recovery.txt:134:shouldn't do any new IOs. Called in task context. This is sort of a

linux/Documentation$ grep -R "process context" .
./spinlocks.txt:110:manipulated from a "process context", ie no interrupts involved. 
./dma-buf-sharing.txt:286:   atomic dma_buf kmaps at the same time (in any given process context).
./DocBook/kernel-locking.tmpl:508:          If you are in a process context (any syscall) and want to
./DocBook/lsm.tmpl:152:have no process context (e.g. network input operations).
```

I understand the difference between process context and irq context, but AFAIK, process and task is not so much different in Linux (I guess I'm clearly wrong).
Could anybody please enlighten me?

Answer (score 0):

In the context of Linux kernel code they are synonymous.